# How to get Select2 to update a ajax call when country value is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I can't seem to find an easy example of how to update the states list when the country list has changed. All examples I've seen to be using all sorts of bits and peices that work depending on version and who is giving the solution.

Can someone help me how this can be easily done without ugly hacks. I've tried this so far and whilst it works, if I change the drop down for the second time, the new values just get appended to the old ones instead of replacing them. I've tried destroying and rebuilding but old values remain.

The data coming back from the server is valid json with id and text values. So far I've had no luck in getting the state list to update with new country state values when the country is changed

```
   <select id="country" name="country" class="form-control" data-placeholder="Select...">
   <optgroup label="Country">
        <option></option>
        <option value="US" > United States</option>
        <option value="AU" > Austrailia</option>
   </optgroup>
   </select>


   <select id="state" name="state" class="form-control" data-placeholder="Select...">
   <optgroup label="State">
      <option></option>
   </optgroup>
   </select>   





   $("#country").select2().on("change", function(e) {
        var country = e.val;

        $.post("states", {
          country_id: country
        }, function(e) {
          if (e)

              $("#states").select2({
                data: e
              });

        })          

   });


   $("#state").select2();
```

These are the values sent back from server

```
   [{ id: 'ALB', text: 'ALABAMA' }, { id: 'ALS', text: 'ALASKA' }, { id: 'ARI', text: 'ARIZONA' }]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the `<option>` tags from the select before setting the new data:

```
$.post("states", {
    country_id: country
  }, function(e) {
     if (e){
       $("#states option").remove();
       $("#states").select2({
           data: e
        });
     }
})
```

You may want to refine my example to avoid removing placeholders, if any.

See also this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/drj84go5/

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to have an input (text) not a select2 and then convert it through select2 function using ajax.

Input:

```
<input type="text" id="states">
```

Javascript:

```
$('#states').select2({
    placeholder: "States...", // placeholder
    allowClear: true,
    minimumInputLength: 0,
    dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop",
    width: '100%',
    ajax: {
        quietMillis: 2500,
        url: "/Search/_SearchStates", // Server-side action
        dataType: 'json',
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                Text: term, // Text to search for
                CountryId: $("#country").val(), // CountryId from #countries
            };
        },
        results: function (data, page) {
            return { results: data };
        },
    },
    formatResult: function (item) {
        return item.StateName; // Table name/description
    },
    id: function (element) {
        return element.StateId; // Table id/code
    },
    formatSelection: function (item) {
        return item.StateName; // Table name/description
    }
});
```

You need to have a server-side action that will give you the list of states.

To get the StateId you need to do:

```
$("#states").select2('val');
```